# Single image texture paint doesn't export with texture

Tags: texturing, export, texture-painting

I'm trying to export my model with the texture I made in texture paint, but the exported models are always untextured. I don't think I've applied the texture properly, I'm still new to all of this. The texture isn't applied in object mode either. I've tried looking up the problem without any luck.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your painting needs to be saved as an image in directory and also be part of your shader tree so that it will show up. Simply adding it as a color input to your diffuse shader will work.